# URL Imageupload / Database set up

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store an image in my database via the URL(image location).
I will like to only store the file name and the php will complete the url. My question: Do i need to add an id field to my table? Also the file maybe different ext(jpg, gif, png) how can the php determine that?

If your curious, I am using this image upload from this [SITE](http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/)

The URL that is generated by the code:

```
http://www.example.com/imageupload/uploads/medium/uniqueimagename.jpg
```

My database structure:

```
size: medium
name: uniqueimagename
ext: jpg/png/gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the image name like this `www.example.com/imageupload/uploads/medium?img=uniqueimagename.jpg` and you can get name by using `$_GET['img']` and yes you have to store the id into your database.Also dont worry abt the extension because the img will store in your folder and just fetch the image name from your db and display in your img tag

Comment: Alright, nice I didnt know that storing the name includes the file extension.

Comment: yes storing the name of the file will also store extension along with file name

Answer (score 0):

The database field that is will hold the image should be a binary. The image name should or could hold the full name; that is with the file extention. Your code can strip the .gif from the the fullname prior to displaying the name.

The other way you can do this is just hold the naming info in the database and the actual image in a folder on your web site.

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to store the image itself in the database.  Looks like just the filename or an ID is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to.

When you store the Image Name, I.E:

```
uniqueimagename.jpg
```

you'll store the extension too, and usually all the images go to the same folder so the path is common.

In PHP you have $_FILES["file"]["type"] variable to know the extension of the [file](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). (or you can use explode like [here](http://cowburn.info/2008/01/13/get-file-extension-comparison/))

if you want you can save the extension apart from the picture's name, but that's up to you

Comment: `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` is provided by the browser, so it shouldn't necessarily be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need an ID field?  As long as the 'uniqueimagename' column contains unique values that's your identifier.

You also don't need to have a separate column for the image type.  The image name will contain the extension.

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer

Comment: Question is rhetorical to point out that the answer is: an ID column is redundant.